# Jetty blocked by company proxy

Tags: java, proxy, jetty

I'm developing an applicatoin that runs in a jetty 9.2.0. 
That works fine so far.

Now I have to implement a feature that requires loading a webpage. I am using this code to load it:

```
@Path( "/bla")
@GET
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public ChildList getBla() {

    ChildList childList = new ChildList();

    String url = "http://www.google.de";
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet( url ) ;
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    CloseableHttpResponse response = null;
    try{
        response = httpClient.execute( httpGet );
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return childList;
}
```

I am getting an "UnknownHostException".
I have tried to start jetty with `-Dhttp.proxyHost`, `-Dhttp.proxyPort`, `-Dhttp.proxyUser` and `-Dhttp.proxyPassword`. I have also tried to set these properties in the method above using `System.setProperty()`.

Then I tried to set the proxy settings in the Java Control Panel.

But I still get the "UnknownHostException".

Is there another way to fix this issue?

Comment: what happens if you try using the ipaddress?

Comment: I also get the UnknownHostException.

Comment: In your client/browser, have you setup proxy?

Comment: I am using fiddler 2.4.8 to test my application. There is no proxy configured, because I am calling http://localhost/myapplication/bla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the posted source was missing setting a proxy. Following code solve the issue:

```
 HttpGet request = new HttpGet( url ) ;
 HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost( System.getProperty( "http.proxyHost" ), Integer.parseInt( System.getProperty( "http.proxyPort" ) ), "http");
 RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy( proxy ).build();
 request.setConfig( config );
```